# How to make json like this from database mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
{
  "idbarang": "ID-75192864",
  "namabarang": "Fruit Tea",
  "jenisbarang": "Minuman",
  "hargabarang": "6000"
}
```

i try this

```
<?php 
include 'koneksi.php';

$idbarang = $_GET['id'];

if($idbarang == !null){
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM data_barang WHERE id_barang = '$idbarang'");

    $result = array();
    $i= 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $result[$i]['idbarang'] = $row['id_barang'];
        $result[$i]['namabarang'] = $row['nama_barang'];
        $result[$i]['jenisbarang'] = $row['jenis_barang'];
        $result[$i]['hargabarang'] = $row['harga_barang'];
        $i++;
    };

    echo json_encode($result);

} else {
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM data_barang");

    $result = array();
    $i= 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $result[$i]['idbarang'] = $row['id_barang'];
        $result[$i]['namabarang'] = $row['nama_barang'];
        $result[$i]['jenisbarang'] = $row['jenis_barang'];
        $result[$i]['hargabarang'] = $row['harga_barang'];
        $i++;
    };

    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

and this the result

```
[
  {
    "idbarang": "ID-75192864",
    "namabarang": "Fruit Tea",
    "jenisbarang": "Minuman",
    "hargabarang": "6000"
  },
  {
    "idbarang": "ID-96037284",
    "namabarang": "Sampoerna",
    "jenisbarang": "Rokok",
    "hargabarang": "12000"
  }
]
```

Comment: So what is wrong with the result you are getting?

Comment: Looks like you got it? The difference is that the first one is one row, the second is 2 rows.

Comment: Why are you expecting only one object, when your query is returning 2 rows? Are you really perhaps asking why it doesn't run the first query, but only runs the second? That's just a guess though...you failed to explain the problem properly. See also [ask].

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: im guessing that the OP wants to do this in one mysql query without the overhead of stitching it all together in PHP

Comment: Not sure what the check `$idbarang == !null` will do?!

Comment: i need result with id !null like first one, but with no id, its okay to get the default result

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking why you are always going through the ELSE and never the IF. Thats because of this IF test

```
if($idbarang == !null){
```

Instead try

```
<?php 
include 'koneksi.php';

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){

    $idbarang = $_GET['id'];
```

You could also simplify that code quite a lot, and protect it from SQL Injection.

```
// Do the renaming of column names as part of the query
$sql = 'SELECT  id_barang as idbarang, nama_barang as namabarang,
                jenis_barang as jenisberang, jenis_barang as hargabarang
        FROM data_barang';

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
    // add the WHERE clause on to the base query
    $sql .= ' WHERE id_barang = ?';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    
} else {
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
}
// as the renaming is done we can just fetch all the results and convert to a JSON document
$result = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thanks i get it, it just follow when the id is null, thanks again sir.

Comment: The point being the id will never be null